# Apache httpd post request limit

Tags: apache, post, nginx, multipartform-data, httpd.conf

We have service posting gzip file to server running behind apache httpd proxy.
Apache is truncating the request body to 64kb.
We are not using multipart/form-data. Is there any way we can modify the apache config to increase the request body limit.

Comment: Are you sure? httpd does not have a limit to the size of your POST requests. If the limit would kick in you would get an error, not fragmentation of the request. Check [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) and similar directives.

Comment: Content-length in the header is 66kb. The length of the body read is 64kb.

Comment: Yes, like I said, Apache does not set a limit for that.